# Getting the username of the user who logs in

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to run the following script:

Here `LoginName1` is a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginName`. The `LoginName1` displays the username in the webpage just fine.
However it does not seem to work. Where am i going wrong?

Here is the full code [latest]:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="~/Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="memberlogin.Default" %>


<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script runat="server" >
    public void redirect()
    {// I have removed previous content - it JUST WONT REDIRECT THE PAGE
        //String loginame = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        //if (loginame == "usertest")
        Response.Redirect( "Default.aspx");   
       }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" >
    <h1>
        <span class="input">Welcome to the members-only page.</span>
    </h1>
    <h2>
        Start Client Side Application.
    </h2>
                        <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    <span class="input">&nbsp;You are not logged in. Click the Login link to sign in</span>
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    <span class="input">You are logged in. Welcome, </span>
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
            <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <table class="style1">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="middle">
            <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        Click on This Image Link To Start The Application<br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:ImageButton   OnClick="click" runat="server" ID="ImageButton1" Height="100px" 
                            ImageUrl="~/Images/loader.jpg" PostBackUrl="~/Loading.aspx" />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" 
                LogoutAction="Redirect" BackColor="White" 
                Font-Underline="True" LogoutPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" />

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: When i move the cursor to`LoginName1` it says "This member is defined more than once.

Comment: Where are you calling redirect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried getting the username from `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`?

Judging from the context, I'm guessing that LoginName1 is a label or another .NET control that does not have any ViewState associated with it. If so, the code above should work.

Comment: Sorry i got that wrong `LoginName1` is `asp:LoginName`, i.e., `System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginName1`...

Answer (score 0):

`System.Web.UI.Page.User.Identity.Name` is not a class. `System.Web.UI.Page` is a class and `User` is a property of type `IPrincipal` which contains a property `Identity` of type `IIdentity` which contains a property `Name` of type `string`.

Is `LoginName1` a `string` which contains the value of `System.Web.UI.Page.User.Identity.Name`? Or is it a control which displays that value? In the former case your code should work, in the later you will need to use `.Text` or `.Value` to get the value of the control.

Comment: It says `This member is defined more than once`